# Security implication of storing a password as a local constant in a method?

Tags: windows, security, delphi, pascal

I would like to educate myself on the subject of most common security anti-patterns.

Hypothetically speaking, what are the security risks of storing a password in the following way:

```
interface

type
  TFoo = class
   procedure DoSomething;
  end;

Implementation

procedure TFoo.DoSomething;
 const
   Password = 'Something';
begin 

end;
```

I know that the correct way would be to use a hashing algorithm to hash the password and save that value in an external file, however I'm really interested in how the password in the example is exposed to a malicious 3rd party.

Comment: Well, it's going to be plain text in the EXE, free for anyone with access to the executable and a hex editor to see.

Comment: Hashing won't help. Storing a password in an executable file is the problem. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Thank you all for fast comments, @DavidHeffernan, I don't want to store password in executable, I just wanted to know how someone gets to that value if one does store it in such a way. For some reason I thought that the compiler would obscure the string in at least some fashion.

Comment: Even obscurity won't help. Not that it happens.

Comment: Do I need to mention that this way all instances of TFoo will have the same password? You only have to crack it once and you instantly gain access to all of them. In all copies of your program. On all platforms you translate it to.

Comment: @mg30rg, it was just an example, thank you for mentioning it tho.

Comment: I think it is worth to mention that if you store the hashed password instead of the plain password in the code as in your example, of course the hash can be obtained from the EXE with an hex viewer/editor but the attacker will not know the original password. If you use this password to access some functionality in your application that attacker should 1) crack your application or 2) bruteforce the hash algorithm to get the original password.

Comment: @Miguel If you have the hash, isn't that enough. What is the app going to do with the hash?

Comment: @David Actually it depends what for the hashed password is used. One example could be that there is some functionality that is only accessible by a password so the app can show a form requesting for the password, apply a hash algorithm on the fly and compare it to the hashed password stored in the EXE. In that context, it does not matter if the attacker can see the hash string inside the EXE or not as he needs to know the original password by brute-forcing the hash (and the attacker must find out also the hash algorithm and/or salt) or crack the application.

Comment: @miguel agreed, my assumption was that the password was to be passed on to another party

Comment: Local or not local does not matter. All structured constants go into data segment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The password will be visible by examining the data in the executable. E.g. use a hex editor or even notepad.

Comment: mg30rg made a good point which was passed over.  If you store the password in the binary then once it is  cracked it is cracked everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to educate myself...

In addition to [egur's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26278720/757830), to answer the unasked question whether any password-stored-in-source-solution would do:

As already explained, a constant String appears literally in the executable.

#### Alternative 1:

```
const
  PW0 = 'pas';
  PW1 = 'swo';
  PW2 = 'rd';
var
  PassWord: String;
...
initialization
  PassWord := PW0 + PW1 + PW2;
```

Result: 'Password' in executable.

#### Alternative 2:

```
const
  PW2 = 'rd';
  PW1 = 'swo';
  PW0 = 'pas';
var
  PassWord: String;
...
initialization
  PassWord := PW0 + PW1 + PW2;
```

Result: 'Password' in executable.

#### Alternative 3:

```
var
  PW2: String = 'rd';
  PW1: String = 'swo';
  PW0: String = 'pas';
  PassWord: String;

initialization
  PassWord := PW0 + PW1 + PW2;
```

Result: 'rd', 'swo' and 'pas' in executable.

Try around yourself some more. Open the executable in Notepad and see for yourself.

Besides, and needless to say, the above practices are no advice but have only complementary value to the question.

Comment: This is known as obfuscation, and does help hide things.  You can also try hiding "in plain sight", by using a password like:
PW: String = 'This program must be run under Win32';
That's a little better, but still, a cracker running in the debugger, will see what you are doing.

Comment: @Chris Done the same ;-) And yes, with a debugger and patience, all bets are off anyhow. The attacker just changes a comparison to its opposite.